# Save / load scipy sparse csr_matrix in portable data format

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How do you save/load a scipy sparse `csr_matrix` in a portable format?  The scipy sparse matrix is created on Python 3 (Windows 64-bit) to run on Python 2 (Linux 64-bit).  Initially, I used pickle (with protocol=2 and fix_imports=True) but this didn't work going from Python 3.2.2 (Windows 64-bit) to Python 2.7.2 (Windows 32-bit) and got the error:

```
TypeError: ('data type not understood', <built-in function _reconstruct>, (<type 'numpy.ndarray'>, (0,), '[98]')).
```

Next, tried `numpy.save` and `numpy.load` as well as `scipy.io.mmwrite()` and `scipy.io.mmread()` and none of these methods worked either.

Comment: mmwrite/mmread should work, as it's a text file format. the possible issue with Linux vs. Windows may be the line endings, CRLF vs LF

Answer (score 144, accepted):

**edit:** scipy 0.19 now has [`scipy.sparse.save_npz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.save_npz.html#scipy.sparse.save_npz) and [`scipy.sparse.load_npz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.load_npz.html#scipy.sparse.load_npz).

```
from scipy import sparse

sparse.save_npz("yourmatrix.npz", your_matrix)
your_matrix_back = sparse.load_npz("yourmatrix.npz")
```

For both functions, the `file` argument may also be a file-like object (i.e. the result of `open`) instead of a filename.

---

Got an answer from the Scipy user group:

> A csr_matrix has 3 data attributes that matter: `.data`, `.indices`, and `.indptr`. All are simple ndarrays, so `numpy.save` will work on them. Save the three arrays with `numpy.save` or `numpy.savez`, load them back with `numpy.load`, and then recreate the sparse matrix object with:

```
new_csr = csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(M, N))
```

So for example:

```
def save_sparse_csr(filename, array):
    np.savez(filename, data=array.data, indices=array.indices,
             indptr=array.indptr, shape=array.shape)

def load_sparse_csr(filename):
    loader = np.load(filename)
    return csr_matrix((loader['data'], loader['indices'], loader['indptr']),
                      shape=loader['shape'])
```

Comment: Any idea if there some reason this was not implemented as a method in the sparse matrix objects? The scipy.io.savemat method seems to work reliably enough though ...

Comment: Note: If filename in save_sparse_csr does not have extension .npz, this will be added automatically. This is not automatically done in the load_sparse_csr function.

Comment: @physicalattraction an easy solution is to add this at the beginning of the loader function
`if not filename.endswith('.npz'): filename += '.npz'`

Comment: Scipy 1.19 now has `scipy.sparse.save_npz` and `load`.

Comment: @hpaulj It might be useful to new users to correct answer: the version is scipy 0.19

Answer (score 40):

Though you write, `scipy.io.mmwrite` and `scipy.io.mmread` don't work for you, I just want to add how they work. This question is the no. 1 Google hit, so I myself started with `np.savez` and `pickle.dump` before switching to the simple and obvious scipy-functions. They work for me and shouldn't be overseen by those who didn't tried them yet.

```
from scipy import sparse, io

m = sparse.csr_matrix([[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]])
m              # <3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>' with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

io.mmwrite("test.mtx", m)
del m

newm = io.mmread("test.mtx")
newm           # <3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>' with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
newm.tocsr()   # <3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>' with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
newm.toarray() # array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Is this the latest solution compared to other answers?

Comment: Yes, currently it is the latest one. You can order the answers by the time of time of creation by clicking on *oldest* in the tab below the question.

Comment: This method fails when only writing `import scipy`. An explicit `from scipy import io` or `import scipy.io` is needed.

Comment: This seems to work much slower than the `np.savez` and `cPickle` solutions, and produce ~3x bigger file. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42101691/304209) for the test details.

Answer (score 29):

Here is performance comparison of the three most upvoted answers using Jupyter notebook. The input is a 1M x 100K random sparse matrix with density 0.001, containing 100M non-zero values:

```
from scipy.sparse import random
matrix = random(1000000, 100000, density=0.001, format='csr')

matrix
<1000000x100000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 100000000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

### `io.mmwrite` / `io.mmread`

```
from scipy.sparse import io

%time io.mmwrite('test_io.mtx', matrix)
CPU times: user 4min 37s, sys: 2.37 s, total: 4min 39s
Wall time: 4min 39s

%time matrix = io.mmread('test_io.mtx')
CPU times: user 2min 41s, sys: 1.63 s, total: 2min 43s
Wall time: 2min 43s    

matrix
<1000000x100000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 100000000 stored elements in COOrdinate format>    

Filesize: 3.0G.
```

(note that the format has been changed from csr to coo).

### `np.savez` / `np.load`

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

def save_sparse_csr(filename, array):
    # note that .npz extension is added automatically
    np.savez(filename, data=array.data, indices=array.indices,
             indptr=array.indptr, shape=array.shape)

def load_sparse_csr(filename):
    # here we need to add .npz extension manually
    loader = np.load(filename + '.npz')
    return csr_matrix((loader['data'], loader['indices'], loader['indptr']),
                      shape=loader['shape'])


%time save_sparse_csr('test_savez', matrix)
CPU times: user 1.26 s, sys: 1.48 s, total: 2.74 s
Wall time: 2.74 s    

%time matrix = load_sparse_csr('test_savez')
CPU times: user 1.18 s, sys: 548 ms, total: 1.73 s
Wall time: 1.73 s

matrix
<1000000x100000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 100000000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

Filesize: 1.1G.
```

### `cPickle`

```
import cPickle as pickle

def save_pickle(matrix, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as outfile:
        pickle.dump(matrix, outfile, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
def load_pickle(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
        matrix = pickle.load(infile)    
    return matrix    

%time save_pickle(matrix, 'test_pickle.mtx')
CPU times: user 260 ms, sys: 888 ms, total: 1.15 s
Wall time: 1.15 s    

%time matrix = load_pickle('test_pickle.mtx')
CPU times: user 376 ms, sys: 988 ms, total: 1.36 s
Wall time: 1.37 s    

matrix
<1000000x100000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 100000000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

Filesize: 1.1G.
```

**Note**: cPickle does not work with very large objects (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38246020/304209)).
In my experience, it didn't work for a 2.7M x 50k matrix with 270M non-zero values.
`np.savez` solution worked well.

### Conclusion

(based on this simple test for CSR matrices)
`cPickle` is the fastest method, but it doesn't work with very large matrices, `np.savez` is only slightly slower, while `io.mmwrite` is much slower, produces bigger file and restores to the wrong format. So `np.savez` is the winner here.

Comment: Thanks! Just a note that at least for me (Py 2.7.11) the line `from scipy.sparse import io` does not work. Instead, just do `from scipy import io`. [Docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.mmwrite.html)

Comment: @patrick thanks for the update. The import change must have been done in `scipy`.

Answer (score 17):

Now you can use `scipy.sparse.save_npz` :
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.save_npz.html

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you have scipy on both machines, you can just use `pickle`.

However, be sure to specify a binary protocol when pickling numpy arrays.  Otherwise you'll wind up with a huge file.

At any rate, you should be able to do this:

```
import cPickle as pickle
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse

# Just for testing, let's make a dense array and convert it to a csr_matrix
x = np.random.random((10,10))
x = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(x)

with open('test_sparse_array.dat', 'wb') as outfile:
    pickle.dump(x, outfile, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

You can then load it with:

```
import cPickle as pickle

with open('test_sparse_array.dat', 'rb') as infile:
    x = pickle.load(infile)
```

Comment: using pickle was my original solution (with protocol=2 and fix_imports=True) but it didn't work going from Python 3.2.2 to Python 2.7.2.  Have added this info to question.

Comment: Please note that, although this seems to be the fastest solution (according to the simple test in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42101691/304209)), `cPickle` does not work with very large matrices ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38246020/304209)).

Answer (score 10):

As of scipy 0.19.0, you can save and load sparse matrices this way:

```
from scipy import sparse

data = sparse.csr_matrix((3, 4))

#Save
sparse.save_npz('data_sparse.npz', data)

#Load
data = sparse.load_npz("data_sparse.npz")
```

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT* Apparently it is simple enough to:

```
def sparse_matrix_tuples(m):
    yield from m.todok().items()
```

Which will yield a `((i, j), value)` tuples, which are easy to serialize and deserialize. Not sure how it compares performance-wise with the code below for `csr_matrix`, but it's definitely simpler. I'm leaving the original answer below as I hope it's informative.

---

Adding my two cents: for me, `npz` is not portable as I can't use it to export my matrix easily to non-Python clients (e.g. PostgreSQL -- glad to be corrected). So I would have liked to get CSV output for the sparse matrix (much like you would get it you `print()` the sparse matrix). How to achieve this depends on the representation of the sparse matrix. For a CSR matrix, the following code spits out CSV output. You can adapt for other representations.

```
import numpy as np

def csr_matrix_tuples(m):
    # not using unique will lag on empty elements
    uindptr, uindptr_i = np.unique(m.indptr, return_index=True)
    for i, (start_index, end_index) in zip(uindptr_i, zip(uindptr[:-1], uindptr[1:])):
        for j, data in zip(m.indices[start_index:end_index], m.data[start_index:end_index]):
            yield (i, j, data)

for i, j, data in csr_matrix_tuples(my_csr_matrix):
    print(i, j, data, sep=',')
```

It's about 2 times slower than `save_npz` in the current implementation, from what I've tested.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to save a `lil_matrix`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix

def save_sparse_lil(filename, array):
    # use np.savez_compressed(..) for compression
    np.savez(filename, dtype=array.dtype.str, data=array.data,
        rows=array.rows, shape=array.shape)

def load_sparse_lil(filename):
    loader = np.load(filename)
    result = lil_matrix(tuple(loader["shape"]), dtype=str(loader["dtype"]))
    result.data = loader["data"]
    result.rows = loader["rows"]
    return result
```

I must say I found NumPy's np.load(..) to be *very slow*. This is my current solution, I feel runs much faster:

```
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
import numpy as np
import json

def lil_matrix_to_dict(myarray):
    result = {
        "dtype": myarray.dtype.str,
        "shape": myarray.shape,
        "data":  myarray.data,
        "rows":  myarray.rows
    }
    return result

def lil_matrix_from_dict(mydict):
    result = lil_matrix(tuple(mydict["shape"]), dtype=mydict["dtype"])
    result.data = np.array(mydict["data"])
    result.rows = np.array(mydict["rows"])
    return result

def load_lil_matrix(filename):
    result = None
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as infile:
        mydict = json.load(infile)
        result = lil_matrix_from_dict(mydict)
    return result

def save_lil_matrix(filename, myarray):
    with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        mydict = lil_matrix_to_dict(myarray)
        json.dump(mydict, outfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
x = sp.csr_matrix([1,2,3])
y = sp.csr_matrix([2,3,4])
np.savez(file, x=x, y=y)
npz = np.load(file)

>>> npz['x'].tolist()
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> npz['x'].tolist().toarray()
array([[1, 2, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

The trick was to call `.tolist()` to convert the shape 0 object array to the original object.

Answer (score 0):

I was asked to send the matrix in a simple and generic format:

```
<x,y,value>
```

I ended up with this:

```
def save_sparse_matrix(m,filename):
    thefile = open(filename, 'w')
    nonZeros = np.array(m.nonzero())
    for entry in range(nonZeros.shape[1]):
        thefile.write("%s,%s,%s\n" % (nonZeros[0, entry], nonZeros[1, entry], m[nonZeros[0, entry], nonZeros[1, entry]]))
```