# Save Large Scipy Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, pickle

I am trying to cPickle a large scipy sparse matrix for later use.  I am getting this error:

```
  File "tfidf_scikit.py", line 44, in <module>
    pickle.dump([trainID, trainX, trainY], fout, protocol=-1)
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

`trainX` is the large sparse matrix, the other two are lists 6mil elements long.

```
In [1]: trainX
Out[1]:
<6034195x755258 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 286674296 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

At this point, Python RAM usage is 4.6GB and I have 16GB of RAM on my laptop.

I think I'm running into a known memory bug for cPickle where it doesn't work with objects that are too big.  I tried `marshal` as well but I don't think it works for scipy matrices.  Can someone offer a solution and preferably an example on how to load and save this?

Python 2.7.5

Mac OS 10.9

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save / load scipy sparse csr\_matrix in portable data format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955448/save-load-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-in-portable-data-format)

Comment: I have the same problem with sparse matrices and pickle, do not think that this is a duplicate question of the one linked.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a multi-gigabyte Numpy matrix (Ubuntu 12.04 with Python 2.7.3 - seems to be this issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2396 ).

I've solved it using `numpy.savetxt()` / `numpy.loadtxt()`. The matrix is compressed adding a .gz file extension when saving.

Since I too had just a single matrix I did not investigate the use of HDF5.

Answer (score 0):

Both `numpy.savetxt` (only for arrays, not sparse matrices) and `sklearn.externals.joblib.dump` (pickling, slow as hell and blew up memory usage) didn't work for me on Python 2.7.

Instead, I used [`scipy.sparse.save_npz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.save_npz.html#scipy.sparse.save_npz) and it worked just fine. Keep in mind that it only works for `csc`, `csr`, `bsr`, `dia` or `coo` matrices.