# why is numpy shape empty?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I have the following

```
(Pdb) training
array(<418326x223957 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 165657096 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
(Pdb) training.shape
()
```

Why is there no shape information?

EDIT: this was what I've done:

```
training, target, test, projectids = generate_features(outcomes, projects, resources)
target = np.array([1. if i == 't' else 0. for i in target])
projectids = np.array([i for i in projectids])

print 'vectorizing training features'
d = DictVectorizer(sparse=True)
training = d.fit_transform(training[:10].T.to_dict().values())
#test_data = d.fit_transform(training.T.to_dict().values())
test_data = d.transform(test[:10].T.to_dict().values())

print 'training shape: %s, %s' %(training.shape[0], training[1])
print 'test shape: %s, %s' %(test_data.shape[0], test_data[1])

print 'saving vectorized instances'
with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    np.save(f, training)
    np.save(f, test_data)
    np.save(f, target)
    np.save(f, projectids)
```

At this point of time, my training's shape was still `(10, 121)`.

Later on, I just reinitialize the 4 variables by

```
with open("../data/f1/training.dat", "rb") as f:
    training = np.load(f)
    test_data = np.load(f)
    target = np.load(f)
    projectids = np.load(f)
```

but the shape was gone.

Comment: You have to provide more context. There is not enough information to infer what is going on. At the very least, show the code you wrote to initialize the classifier and the training data.

Comment: Sparse matrices aren't NumPy arrays. They're not even considered arraylikes; most NumPy routines have no idea what to do with one. It might be useful to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955448/save-load-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-in-portable-data-format

Comment: It appears in this case that `numpy` does known what to do with a `sparse` matrix - wrap it in an object array.  I'm using numpy 1.9dev if that makes a difference.

Comment: user2357112 is correct. I have modified and used pickle instead

Answer (score 7):

There is shape information in

```
array(<418326x223957 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 165657096 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
```

This is an array of one item, and 0 dimensions, hence the shape `()`.  That one item is of `dtype=object`.  Specifically it is a sparse array - with dimensions shown in the display `<418...x22...`.

I was going ask about `DictVectorizer` and `fit_transform`, but that doesn't matter.  It's the save and load operation that changes values.

My guess is that you are not loading the file that you just wrote.

---

Your `np.save(f,training)` is wrapping the sparse matrix in an `np.array` with dtype `object`.   That's what you see on load.

```
training = training.item()
```

takes the sparse matrix out of that array wrapper.

Is `418326x223957` the shape of `training` with the full data set, and `(10, 121)` the shape for a reduced debugging set?