# Writing both float and integer on a text file from one numpy array

Tags: python, text, numpy, ascii

I have a `nxm` numpy array that either has positive values with 8 decimal points like `0.02113342` or `NoValue` data that is `-9999`. I am using the line below to make a text file from the numpy array

```
numpy.savetxt("result.asc", Numpy_Array, fmt="%.8f")#2D array to ASCII
```

However, I will have `-9999.00000000` instead of `-9999`. I open the file and replace those numbers with `-9999` using the following code:

```
with file("result.asc", 'r') as original: 
    data = original.read()
    new = data.replace(str(-9999)+".00000000", str(-9999))
with file("result.asc", 'w') as modified:
    modified.write(new)
```

Is there a more elegant way to write `-9999` rather than `-9999.00000000` from the beginning instead of opening the whole file again and replacing them?

Comment: Why not let the `-9999.00000000` persist?

Comment: The ASCII file will be much bigger and there is no value to it! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `fmt="%.8g"`.  It is not the same as `"%.8f"` for all floating point values (e.g. for very small values, it uses exponential notation), but it might work for the cases you have.
(See the table at https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language with the floating point types--scroll down a bit--for an explanation of the difference between the `f` and `g` formats.)

```
In [188]: x
Out[188]: 
array([[    0.20134635, -9999.        ],
       [    0.9287082 ,     0.00000123],
       [    0.77482316,     0.27246281],
       [    0.40529746,     0.41133371]])

In [189]: np.savetxt("xf.dat", x, fmt="%.8f")

In [190]: np.savetxt("xg.dat", x, fmt="%.8g")

In [191]: !cat xf.dat
0.20134635 -9999.00000000
0.92870820 0.00000123
0.77482316 0.27246281
0.40529746 0.41133371

In [192]: !cat xg.dat
0.20134635 -9999
0.9287082 1.2345679e-06
0.77482316 0.27246281
0.40529746 0.41133371
```

Here's the actual value of `x[1,1]`:

```
In [193]: x[1,1]
Out[193]: 1.23456789e-06
```

Alternatively, take a look at this answer to a similar question: [How to format in numpy savetxt such that zeros are saved only as "0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691755/how-to-format-in-numpy-savetxt-such-that-zeros-are-saved-only-as-0/24699373#24699373)

Comment: It totally worked! Perfect! Can you please add an explanation about the differences between `fmt="%.8g"` and `fmt="%.8f"` in your answer?

Comment: @bikhaab: I added a link to the Python documentation.