# numpy number array to strings with trailing zeros removed

Tags: string, numpy, format

question: is my method of converting a numpy array of numbers to a numpy array of strings with specific number of decimal places AND trailing zeros removed the 'best' way?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1.12345, 1.2, 0.1, 0, 1.230000])
print np.core.defchararray.rstrip(np.char.mod('%.4f', x), '0')
```

outputs:

```
['1.1235' '1.2' '0.1' '0.' '1.23']
```

which is the desired result. (I am OK with the rounding issue)

Both of the functions 'rstrip' and 'mod' are numpy functions which means this is fast but is there a way to accomplish this with ONE built in numpy function?  (ie. does 'mod' have an option that I couldn't find?)  It would save the overhead of returning copies twice which for very large arrays is slow-ish.

thanks!

Comment: why don't you just use  `print np.char.mod('%0.4f', x)`?

Comment: @Dalek because that would not remove trailing zeros.  The reason I want to remove the zeros is it will make my files smaller. I am manually creating some ascii GIS rasters and would prefer to keep the large files as small as possible.  Speed-wise, the additional operation to remove trailing zeros is not a bid deal so I consider it worth it for the gain of having smaller files. It would be fine for a few files to be larger than needed but I'm planning to do some quite large scale stuff...it'll add up. So, I am OK with the speed of what I use, but I am curious if anyone has a slicker way.

Comment: If you are OK with 5 "signifcant digits" instead of 4 decimal places, you could use `np.char.mod("%.5g", x)`.

Comment: Are you creating the files with `np.savetxt`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser  No, I need to have some headers at the top of the file for GIS.

Comment: savetxt could be good if one of the 2 features existed:  1) can capture the output of the savetxt command so I can output it to my file of choice.  2) accept a file handle, not just a filename. this would allow me to write my headers and then call savetxt to do the rest.

Comment: What version of numpy are you using?  In the latest version of numpy, `savetxt` accepts a file handle: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691755/how-to-format-in-numpy-savetxt-such-that-zeros-are-saved-only-as-0/

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser  you are correct "filename or file handle".  I totally missed that when I scanned the docs. I'm curious if it's faster...I will try and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Warren Weckesser for providing valuable comments. Credit to him.

I converted my code to use:

```
formatter = '%d'
if num_type == 'float':
  formatter = '%%.%df' % decimals
np.savetxt(out, arr, fmt=formatter)
```

where out is a file handle to which I had already written my headers. Alternatively, I could also use the `headers=` argument in `np.savetxt`.  I have no clue how I didn't see those options in the documentation.

For a numpy array 1300 by 1300, creating the line by line output as I did before (using `np.core.defchararray.rstrip(np.char.mod('%.4f', x), '0')`) took ~1.7 seconds and using `np.savetxt` takes 0.48 seconds.

So `np.savetxt` is a cleaner, more readable, and faster solution.

Note: 
I did try:

```
np.savetxt(out, arr, fmt='%.4g')
```

in an effort to not have a switch based on number type but it did not work as I had hoped.