# cPickle:SystemError: error return without exception set

Tags: ubuntu, gzip, pickle, system-error

While dumping large matrix (170000*20000) as follows

```
 cPickle.dump(train_set,gzip.open('train.pickle.gz','wb'), cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

I get following error:

```
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

How would I deal in this case?

Answer (score 5):

`cPickle` can't be used for storing very large objects ( see http://bugs.python.org/issue11564 ).

You have several options:

- split the data into chunks and store it in multiple files
- [numpy.save](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)
- [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/) <- my favorite because of its convenient numpy-like interface, plus the data are stored in `hdf5` which enables interopability with other software/languages.
- [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/)