# Applying a matrix decomposition for classification using a saved W matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, matrix-decomposition, nmf

I'm performing an NMF decomposition on a tf-idf input in order to perform topic analysis.

```
def decomp(tfidfm, topic_count):
    model = decomposition.NMF(init="nndsvd", n_components=topic_count,     max_iter=500)
    H = model.fit_transform(tfidfm)
    W = model.components_
    return W, H
```

This returns *W*, a model definition consisting of topics to term assignments, and *H*, a document to topic assignment matrix

So far so good, I can use H to classify documents based on their association via term frequency to a list of topics which in turn are also based on their association to term frequency.

I'd like to save the topic-term-associations to disk so I can reapply them later - and have adopted the method described here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955448] to store the sparse-matrix reperesentation of W.

So what I'd like to do now, is perform the same process, only fixing the topic-definition matrix W.

In the documentation, it appears that I can set W in the calling parameters something along the lines of:

```
def applyModel(tfidfm,W,topic_count):
    model = decomposition.NMF(init="nndsvd", n_components=topic_count, max_iter=500)
    H = model.fit_transform(X=tfidfm, W=W)
    W = model.components_
    return W, H
```

And I've tried this, but it doesn't appear to work.

I've tested by compiling a W matrix using a differently sized vocabulary, then feeding that into the `applyModel` function, the shape of the resulting matrices should be defined (or I should say, that is what I'm intending) by the W model, but this isn't the case.

The short version of this question is: How can I save the topic-model generated from a matrix decomposition, such that I can use it to classify a different document set than the one used to originally generate it?

In other terms, if **V**=**WH**, then how can I return **H**, given **V** and **W**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial equation is: [image: initial equation] and we solve it for [image: H] like this: [image: How to solve it for H].

Here [image: inverse of W] denotes the inverse of the matrix [image: W], which exists only if [image: W] is nonsingular.

The multiplication order is, as always, important. If you had [image: if the order is changed], you'd need to multiply [image: V] by the inverse of [image: W] the other way round: [image: no description].

Comment: Of course! Maths wins again. I'll post the solution I used to perform the matrix multiplication/inverse to get H. It looks as though I'm getting meaningful results for the application I'm applying it to. I will mark as answered shortly but would like to leave open to invite any additional answers - I was anticipating something baked into scikit and don't want to replicate a process if there's already something there.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's the rewritten `applyModel` function that takes into account the answer from ForceBru (uses an import of `scipy.sparse.linalg`)

```
def applyModel(tfidfm,W):
    H = tfidfm * linalg.inv(W)
    return H
```

This returns (assuming an aligned vocabulary) a mapping of documents to topics **H** based on a pregenerated topic-model **W** and document feature matrix **V** generated by tfidf.