# save_npz method missing from scipy.sparse

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using 0.17 version of `scipy` library on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit system in `python v3.5`. I am unable to find [scipy.sparse.save_npz](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.save_npz.html#scipy.sparse.save_npz) operation in the library, although it is mentioned in the latest documentation.

On listing the callable methods from `scipy.sparse` object I am getting the following output:

```
['SparseEfficiencyWarning',
 'SparseWarning',
 'Tester',
 'bench',
 'block_diag',
 'bmat',
 'bsr_matrix',
 'coo_matrix',
 'cs_graph_components',
 'csc_matrix',
 'csr_matrix',
 'dia_matrix',
 'diags',
 'dok_matrix',
 'eye',
 'find',
 'hstack',
 'identity',
 'issparse',
 'isspmatrix',
 'isspmatrix_bsr',
 'isspmatrix_coo',
 'isspmatrix_csc',
 'isspmatrix_csr',
 'isspmatrix_dia',
 'isspmatrix_dok',
 'isspmatrix_lil',
 'kron',
 'kronsum',
 'lil_matrix',
 'rand',
 'random',
 'spdiags',
 'spmatrix',
 'test',
 'tril',
 'triu',
 'vstack']
```

The list should have contained `save_npz` method but it is not there. If the method has been deprecated then please tell me some good alternatives for saving and loading sparse matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `scipy.sparse.save_npz / load_npz` are new in version 0.19.0 http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/release.0.19.0.html

Comment: What is its best alternative in 0.17 version?

Comment: Find and download the relevant file on `github`.  It appears to be self contained python, so should work with earlier versions.

Comment: Similar code has been around for several years: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955448/save-load-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-in-portable-data-format/42101691#42101691. The MATLAB compatible `io.savemat/loadmat` also handles sparse matrices (`csc` format).