# numpy.ndarray sparse matrix to dense

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I want to run `sklearn`'s `RandomForestClassifier` on some data that is packed as a `numpy.ndarray` which happens to be sparse.
Calling `fit` gives `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`. From other posts I understand that random forest cannot handle sparse data.

I expected the object to have a `todense` method, but it doesn't.

```
>>> X_train
array(<1443899x1936774 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 141256894 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
      dtype=object)
>>> type(X_train)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I tried wrapping it with a SciPy `csr_matrix` but that gives errors as well.

Is there any way to make random forest accept this data?
(not sure that dense would actually fit in memory, but that's another thing...)

**EDIT 1**

The code generating the error is just this:

```
X_train = np.load('train.npy') # this returns a ndarray
train_gt = pd.read_csv('train_gt.csv')

model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, train_gt.target)
```

As for the suggestion to use `toarray()`, ndarray does not have such method.
`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'toarray'`

Moreover, as mentioned, for this particular data I would need terabytes of memory to hold the array. Is there an option to run `RandomForestClassifier` with a sparse array?

**EDIT 2**

It seems that the data should have been saved using SciPy's sparse as mentioned here [Save / load scipy sparse csr_matrix in portable data format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955448/save-load-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-in-portable-data-format).
When using NumPy's save/load more data should have been saved.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we can see which code causes the error. Right now, you're only showing the type of `X_train`, but neither its shape nor how you are feeding it into the `RandomForestClassifier`. Likely, the data is not shaped correctly, see the answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the data should have been saved using SciPy's sparse as mentioned here [Save / load scipy sparse csr_matrix in portable data format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955448/save-load-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-in-portable-data-format). When using NumPy's save/load more data should have been saved.

`RandomForestClassifier` can run using data in this format.
The code has been running for 1:30h now, so hopefully it will actually finish :-)

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> X_train
array(<1443899x1936774 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 141256894 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
      dtype=object)
```

means that your code, or something it calls, has done `np.array(M)` where `M` is a `csr` sparse matrix.  It just wraps that matrix in a object dtype array.

To use a sparse matrix in code that doesn't take sparse matrices, you have to first convert them to dense:

```
 arr = M.toarray()    # or M.A same thing
 mat = M.todense()    # to make a np.matrix
```

But given the dimensions and number of nonzero elements, it is likely that this conversion will produce a `memory error`.

Comment: The object I get is `ndarray` which does not have `toarray` or `todense`. I cannot see any method that would convert that to a csr_matrix

Comment: Use `X_train[()]` to take the wrongly saved matrix out of the array wrapper.  Then  use `toarray`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the `toarray` method, as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix).

So you can do, e.g., `X_dense = X_train.toarray()`.

Of course, then your computer crashes (unless you have the requisite 22 terabytes of RAM?).

Comment: `ndarray` does not have to `toarray` method, otherwise I would not pose the question. And you are correct -- the array would require terabytes (I think "just" 2.2) which is not practical.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've loaded a csr matrix using np.load, you need to convert it from an np array back to a csr matrix. You said you tried wrapping it with csr_matrix, but that's not the contents of the array, you need to all the `.all()`

```
temp = csr_matrix(X_train.all())
X_train = temp.toarray()
```