# Sklearn One Hot Encoding produces non-tabular output

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a data set like this:

```
           Entity  Year  Mean
0      Afghanistan  2016  0.99
1           Africa  2016  0.99
2          Albania  2016  0.99
3          Algeria  2016  0.99
4         Americas  2016  0.99
...            ...   ...   ...
11346        World  1961  0.05
11347        Yemen  1961  0.05
11348   Yugoslavia  1961  0.05
11349       Zambia  1961  0.05
11350     Zimbabwe  1961  0.05
```

and I need to encode Entity column in this data set. I used `OneHotEncoder` in `sklearn`. Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
x_yam = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x_yam))
```

But after encoding it gives me something like this:

```
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (0, 229)  2016.0
  (0, 230)  0.99
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (1, 229)  2016.0
  (1, 230)  0.99
  (2, 2)    1.0
  (2, 229)  2016.0
  (2, 230)  0.99
  (3, 3)    1.0
  (3, 229)  2016.0
  (3, 230)  0.99
  (4, 4)    1.0
  (4, 229)  2016.0
  (4, 230)  0.99
  (5, 5)    1.0
  (5, 229)  2016.0
  (5, 230)  0.99
  (6, 6)    1.0
  (6, 229)  2016.0
  (6, 230)  0.99
  (7, 7)    1.0
  (7, 229)  2016.0
  (7, 230)  0.99
  (8, 8)    1.0
  : :
```

I can't use this data for my ML model, so how can I use `OneHotEncoder` correctly to encode my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column transformer has opted to transform into a scipy sparse matrix because the one-hot encoder does and it has sufficiently many columns compared to the passthrough.

Many ML models will accept sparse input, and this will be much more memory-efficient.

Otherwise, you can force dense arrays throughout by specifying `sparse_threshold=0.0` in the `ColumnTransformer`, or `sparse=False` in the `OneHotEncoder`.  Or you can cast the sparse output to dense after transforming; you cannot do that with the `np.array(...)` you've tried, but using `.todense()` instead will work (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55639087/10495893).